How to enable Ctrl+alt+c copy to system clipboard from neovim buffer?
I would like to use Ctrl+Alt+c / Ctrl+Alt+v to copy and paste to a vim buffer just like I'm able to in a terminal. While Ctrl+Alt+v works to paste stuff from system clipboard to the buffer, copying with Ctrl+Alt+c doesn't. Also it seems that if I use my mouse to select the buffer contents the line numberings are also selected.
I also tried copying to system clipboard with "+y but then nvim says:
clipboard: No provider. Try ":checkhealth" or ":h clipboard"
When I do that I see that apparently I need to somehow hook up my clipboard to nvim. Since I'm using Ununtu 20.04 with X11 (not wayland), I figure I must test the $DISPLAY variable, which in my case is set to 1. But then how to hook up xclip to nvim? I'm a bit lost since I don't have a solid understanding of the mechanisms involved and I didn't find any good resource to read up on it.

This question is similar to: How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
